# how get the callback in different thread other than main thread - android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am creating a library function which should register for the data listener and start scanning barcode. When the barcode is read, `onData()` callback is triggered. The function should wait until the barcode is read and data is processed and return the result. I tried to wait by using a `lockObject.wait()` until I get the data in `onData()` function. But as the callback is also triggered on the main thread it was waiting forever. So I thought of moving the callback listener to new thread. But when I create a new thread and tried to register data listener, it throws `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

I tried searching and many suggests to move the functionality to main thread but I can't as my library function waits on main thread. What's the best way to fix this issue or to redesign this functionality implementation?

Comment: Doing it directly would depend on the details of the unmentioned barcode scanner implementation.  But as an alternative, why not just have onData() on the main thread signal (or push the result to) the waiting background thread?

Comment: @ChrisStratton The library is a synchronous API call, so it actually waits on main thread not the background one. So I was thinking of creating a callback listener in worker thread and push the result to main thread. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: StartActivityForResult.  I'm just saying.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: If it is waiting on the "main thread" then it is a **fundamentally broken design**.  Perhaps you should be calling into the library from a background thread, not the main thread.